# Melhor forma tag Select em Php sem framework com padrão de projeto DAO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito da melhor forma para implementar um método que percorre um select comum utilizando padrão DAO com PDO.

Seria apropriado eu fazer dessa forma, meu código inteiro na view:

```
$conexao = new PDOUtil ();
$consulta = $conexao->getStance()->prepare( "SELECT id_pagina, tema FROM pagina" );
$consulta->execute ();

?>    
      <select required="" name="id_pagina">
          <option disabled="">Selecione uma página</option>
          <?php while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?> 
          <option value="<?php echo $linha->id_pagina;?>"><?php echo   $linha->tema;?></option>
          <?php } ?>
      </select>
```

Ou o melhor seria fazer toda essa parte dentro da minha classe DAO exemplo misturando HTML e PHP dentro das querys:

```
        class Dao
    $conexao = new PDOUtil ();
     public function buscarTudo() {
     $consulta = $conexao->getStance()->prepare( "SELECT id_pagina, tema FROM pagina" );
$consulta->execute ();


      echo "<select required="" name="id_pagina">";
      echo"<option disabled="">Selecione uma página</option>";
      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
          echo "<option value=" $linha->id_pagina;">"
          echo "$linha->tema;?></option>"
          }
      echo "</select>";
}
```

e depois somente chamar esse método dentro da minha view. Vocês teriam outra sugestão?

Se o código estiver errado não liguem é por que digitei por aqui mesmo, agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua classe DAO deve ser responsável apenas por executar consultas no banco de dados, evite saídas de texto para ter problema com header aready sent.

Digamos o usuário clicou em link que monta uma tela de cadastrado, o ideal é esse arquivo ou controller chamar o DAO armazernar o resultado em uma variável e despacha-la para a view isso pode ser feito com um template engine como o smarty, twig ou pode ser feito manualmente, basta chamar um include/require que tenha o html, lá faça o foreach para exibir os options.

O conteúdo do template chamado pelo include/required la seria mais ou menos dessa forma:

Arquivo controller ou equivalente:

```
<?php
   $dao = new Dao();
   $paginas = $dao->buscarTodo();

   include 'template.php';
```

template.php

```
<select name="id_pagina">
   <option value="">Selecione</option>
   <?php foreach($paginas as $pagina) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $pagina->id_pagina;?>"><?php echo $pagina->tema;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Outra abordagem é criar uma classe que com métodos gerem HTML.

```
public static function montarOptions($itens){
    $options = '';
    foreach($itens as $item){
        $options .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $item->id_pagina, $item->tema);
    }
    return $options;
}
```

O controller fica o mesmo o que muda um pouco é o template:

```
<select name="id_pagina">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <?php echo montarOptions($paginas); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Acho que vc não entedeu minha pergunta.  Eu sei a responsabilidade da classe dao a questão que coloquei seria a melhor forma de criar o select sem misturar o html na classe dao

Comment: @André Martins o segundo parágrafo não responde? Ou a resposta teria que dizer pq a primeira opção é melhor que a segunda vice-versa?

Comment: Mais ou menos eu gostaria de um exemplo obrigado