# PHP- Mostrar resultados de query num select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Fiz um input para o admin escrever uma mensagem para um utilizador especifico. O utilizador será selecionado por um select que vai buscar à tabela dos utilizadores os nomes e lista-os todos.
Depois de selecionar alguém, o admin pode escrever a mensagem, a qual seria gravada na bd com o campo "utilizador" igual ao que foi previamente selecionado.

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;

$rows = db_select("SELECT name FROM utilizadores");
if ($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    echo $rows;
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}
```

Não estou a conseguir fazer o echo por isso suponho que a query esteja mal feita, e caso não esteja, como listo o resultado no select? Suponho que seja dentro do loop 'while' tipo:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
        ?>
       <select>
            <option>$rows[]</option>
       </select> 
       <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa imprirmir com echo o item atual da consulta($row) e não o array completo($rows).

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    ?>

<option>
   <?php echo $row['name'];?>
</option>
```

Caso o valor exibido no option seja o mesmo do que será enviado, pode-se omitir o atributo value do option.

[Outra forma de montar um select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60576/91)

Comment: obrigado! já consegui fazer o select.